# Terraform apply command fails when runs twice in Gitlab pipeline and resources were already created

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I'm quite new with Terraform and I'm trying to replicate in my terraform configuration the stack I have already built for production (basically: Api gateway - Lambda - DynamoDB).

If I run `terraform init`, `terraform plan` and then `terraform apply` from my local host, everything is created as I want.

The problem arises when it comes to my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, as Terraform complains about the existing resources (the first time runs properly, the second time complains and throws an error).

My Terraform steps in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
plan:
  stage: plan
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  script:
    - cd terraform
    - rm -rf .terraform
    - terraform --version
    - terraform init
    - terraform plan

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  script:
   - cd terraform
   - terraform init
   - terraform apply -auto-approve
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
```

I see in my pipeline console the following error:
[image]

So after some Googling I saw that maybe the `terraform import` command could help.

Then added this `import` command to my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
 script:
 - cd terraform
 - terraform init
 - terraform import aws_dynamodb_table.demo-dynamodb-table demo-dynamodb-table
 - terraform apply -auto-approve
```

And the error in the Gitlab console was:
[image]

In the meantime I tried also this last change locally, and the error was:
[image]

So to summarize: I would need to know how to use Terraform in the right way to be able to run the `apply` command in my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline without conflicts with the resource that was created in the previous run of this same pipeline.

Comment: First thing to do here is have the `plan` from the first stage output a plan file that the `apply` in the second stage executes on. Second is that this problem is probably related to the terraform state not persisting between pipeline executions, which makes sense since these actions are occurring within a stateless container. Then this becomes more of a TF/Docker problem than anything else.

Comment: @MattSchuchard is correct here, this is a state problem. You should be persisting your state remotely such as in S3. Read [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) for more information. Also you shouldn't ever post screenshots of text. Copy the text into a quote or code block into your question instead so that people can actually read the text and copy/paste it etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, you need to store the Terraform state.

In my GitLab projects, I use a S3 bucket to store the Terraform state. But, have the CI pipeline fill in the key based on the GitLab project's path by setting the `TF_CLI_ARGS_init` environment variable.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "bucket-name-here"
    region = "us-west-2"
    # key = $CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG
  }
}
```

I also set the Terraform workspace based on the project. This can be modified to support branches. I also set the `name` variable to the project name, for use in the Terraform configuration. And, set input to false so that the CI job doesn't get hung up on user prompts.

```
variables:
  TF_INPUT: "false"
  TF_WORKSPACE: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
  TF_VAR_name: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"
  TF_CLI_ARGS_init: "-upgrade=true"
```

For destroys, I also make sure to delete the workspace, so that there isn't stuff left over in the bucket.

```
.destroy:
  extends: .terraform
  stage: Cleanup
  script:
    - terraform init
    - terraform destroy
      -auto-approve
    - export WORKSPACE=$TF_WORKSPACE
    - export TF_WORKSPACE=default
    - terraform workspace delete "$WORKSPACE"
```

Comment: Great! I will try that too embrace better practices, thanks.